# c++ - reusing std::fstream

Tags: c++, c++11, stream

After I reading to end `std::fstream` using `read` method I cannot `seekg` to begining(`tellg` returns -1). Is there a way to reuse `std::fstream` without closeing and reopening it?

```
if (!stream->is_open();)
{
    throw "stream is closed";
}
stream->seekg(0, stream->end);
std::fstream::pos_type lenght = stream->tellg();
stream->seekg(0, stream->beg);

if (0 != stream->tellg())
{
    throw "could not set seek to beginig";
}

char* buffer = new char[lenght];


stream->read(buffer, lenght);

*data = buffer;
return lenght;
```

1st run returns ok.
2nd run throws (cannot seek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the stream has gone into failure-mode (i.e., `std::ios_base::failbit` is set) it won't do anything useful until this flag is `clear()`ed. It is probably sufficient to use

```
stream->clear();
```